# Align levels in a tree using tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'd like all levels in my tree diagram to be aligned vertically. The problem is that some branches 'skip' a level. Specifically, all x's and all C's should be next to each other (the rest is fine as it is). I managed to to this for the x's by specifying the distance from the root. But the C's are all over the place.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
    \Tree   [.{\textbf{W}} 
                [.{\textbf{S}} 
                    [.\textit{Onset} [.C {\textit{xx}} ] 
                                    [.C {\textit{x}} ] ] 
                    [.\textit{Reim}
                        [.\textit{Nukleus}  [.C {\textit{x}} ]
                                    [.C {\textit{x}} ] ]
                        [.\textit{Koda}         {C} ] ] ]
                [.{\textbf{S}} 
                    [.\textit{Onset} [.C {\textit{x}} ] ]
                    [.\textit{Reim }    
                        [.\textit{Nukleus} [.C {\textit{x}} ] ]
                        [.\textit{Koda} {C} {C} ] ] ]
                            ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with your code i obtain the following image:

[image]

Comment: i took liberty and add to your question the image generated by your code (on my computer). do you like that `C` below `Onset` is at the same level as are `C` below `Nukleus`? welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thank you for the image, Zarko. I would like  the C below Onset moved down to the same level as the C below Nukleus (as you said). I would also like the C below Koda at the same level (moved up).

Comment: This would be easiest with Forest, but you'd have to change the way you specify the tree slightly. Then you can just say `before typesetting nodes={where content={C}{tier=c, font=\upshape}{font=\itshape, if content={x}{tier=x}{}}}` in the tree's preamble. (And drop the explicit `\textit`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with cfr that `forest` is the way to go for this kind of tree, but if you have a lot of them and you don't mind some branches looking a bit odd you could simply add extra brackets around the nodes that are at the wrong level.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={font=\itshape}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
    \Tree   [.{\textbf{\upshape W}} 
                [.{\textbf{\upshape S}} 
                    [.Onset  [[.C {xx} ]] 
                [[.C {x} ]] ] 
                    [.Reim
                        [.Nukleus  [.C {x} ]
                                    [.C {x} ] ]
                        [.Koda       [.C  {x} ] ] ] ]
                [.{\textbf{\upshape S}} 
                    [.Onset [[.C {x} ]] ]
                    [.Reim     
                        [.Nukleus [.C {x} ] ]
                        [.Koda [.C {x} ] [.C {x} ] ] ] ]
                            ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

The extra `x` nodes I added to the tree don't affect the placement of the Cs. You can still align the C nodes and the `x` nodes even with missing `x` nodes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={font=\itshape}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
    \Tree   [.{\textbf{\upshape W}} 
                [.{\textbf{\upshape S}} 
                    [.Onset  [[.C {xx} ]] 
                [[.C {x} ]] ] 
                    [.Reim
                        [.Nukleus  [.C {x} ]
                                    [.C {x} ] ]
                        [.Koda       [.C   ] ] ] ]
                [.{\textbf{\upshape S}} 
                    [.Onset [[.C {x} ]] ]
                    [.Reim     
                        [.Nukleus [.C {x} ] ]
                        [.Koda [.C  ] [.C  ] ] ] ]
                            ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I wanted. It's much more elegant than my own solution. I don't mind the odd looking branches under the first Onset, and I'm happy that I don't have to use another package.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. In the longer term, though, it's probably a good idea to consider switching to `forest`. I was a big `tikz-qtree` fan but now do all my trees with `forest`.

Comment: Has rather more 'x's than the original, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: If you don't draw the odd-looking edges, could you add non-odd-looking ones by hand? @Max

Comment: @cfr Yes, of course you could. This is more or less what I did in my own solution. This obviously adds a bunch of work that needs to put into the whole thing, which gets tedious quickly. Also: You're right about this tree having more x's than the initial one - if you delete the ones I don't want, the solution doesn't work, which is a shame.

Comment: @cfr and Max There's no problem deleting the X's.  See edit.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, that works perfectly. I should have been able to modify your initial solution myself but somehow couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has yet answered, here's a Forest version:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  before typesetting nodes={
    where level<=1{font=\bfseries}{if content={C}{tier=c}{font=\itshape, if content={x}{tier=x}{}},}
  },
  [W 
    [S
      [Onset
        [C[xx]][C[x]]
      ]
      [Reim
        [Nukleus
          [C[x]] [C[x]]
        ]
        [Koda
          [C]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [S
      [Onset
        [C[x]]
      ]
      [Reim
        [Nukleus
          [C[x]]
        ]
        [Koda
          [C][C]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest version]

The nice thing about this, of course, is that Forest does all the work: no need to hard-code distances or change them if the content or structure of the tree is modified later.

Comment: i wait on your forest solution :-). my search in `tikz-qtree` manual doesn't give me a hope, that such image is possible to draw with it . (+1)

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I've just settled on specifying nodes and then moving each node individually. This is a bit tedious and I'll have to do it for every individual tree, so if someone has a better solution, please tell me.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{frontier/.style={distance from root=150pt}}
    \Tree   [.{\textbf{W}} 
    [.{\textbf{S}} 
    [.\textit{Onset} [.\node at (0,-1.1) {C}; {\textit{xx}} ] 
    [.\node at (0,-1.1) {C}; {\textit{x}} ] ] 
    [.\textit{Reim}
    [.\textit{Nukleus}  [.C {\textit{x}} ]
    [.C {\textit{x}} ] ]
    [.\textit{Koda}         \node at (0,1) {C}; ] ] ]
    [.{\textbf{S}} 
    [.\textit{Onset} [.\node at (0,-1.1) {C}; {\textit{x}} ] ]
    [.\textit{Reim }    
    [.\textit{Nukleus} [.C {\textit{x}} ] ]
    [.\textit{Koda} \node at (0,1.1) {C}; \node at (0,1.1) {C}; ] ] ]
    ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me the desired result:

[image: All C's are (roughly) level.]

Comment: Since the majority of your nodes are `\itshape` it would save you a lot of markup to add `\tikzset{every tree node/.style={font=\itshape}}` and then simply add `\upshape` inside the bolded nodes.  Then you don't need to add `\textit` to every node.

Comment: Well, you've seen at least two better solutions, so I'm not clear what you're hoping people to come up with here.

Comment: @cfr I saw one better solution by the time I posted this, which used a package that I didn't want to use. The solution I accepted was posted later, but it isn't perfect either (see my recent comment on there).

Comment: That's why we're telling you that Forest is the way to go here. I mean, not just me, but also @AlanMunn said as much. Either you have to do more tedious stuff yourself or you have to use a package which does (most) of that tedious stuff for you. Alan provided a solution of the first kind; I provided one of the second. I day say there will soon be an `istgame` solution, too, although its syntax is much less similar to what you're using now than Forest's.

Comment: @cfr Yes and I appreciate your solution, although it's not what I'm looking for, because I don't want to get into a new package at the moment. I'll have a look at `forest` when I have the time. The modifications that @AlanMunn made to his solution are spot on, exactly what I was looking for. They also avoid the tedious stuff that I thought was necessary in my own solution. I'm happy that he could get rid of that within the package that I've been working with. (His solution is also immediately applicable to other trees of the same sort (which don't only contain C's and x's), which is nice too.)